# How nodes are discovered with PoS?

Tags: proof-of-stake

On the PoW model, in order to find the proper network all you need is the address of a single correct node. You're able to identify the proper network by simply picking up the one with the most accumulated computing power.

On the PoS model, the solution isn't as obvious to me. It seems that, in order to find the proper network, you must absolutely trust whoever gave you the IP of a node. That seems to put a "trust" barrier on network entrance.

Am I missing something, is there any clever trick to solve this issue?

Comment: A new discovery protocol is in the works in geth, maybe you want to ask in that direction.

Comment: "Discovery v5" https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/17/whoa-geth-1-5/

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, does it?

Comment: That's why I'm adding a comment instead of an answer, to help you, in your inquire for truth :-)

Comment: @HermanJunge Oh I see, sorry...

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking how a node, in PoS, can trust another node it is connecting to for the purpose of downloading the blockchain, as it with PoS quite easy to "fake" the entire blockchain from the beginning of time (generating blocks requires little work).

PoW, on the other hand, is impossible to fake unless you buy a very very very large amount of computing power and generate valid blocks (maybe leaving out a transaction or two to give yourself some extra Eth).

To solve this issue, see this [blog post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/11/25/proof-stake-learned-love-weak-subjectivity/) about weak subjectivity. Essentially, when you sync your PoS node for the first time, you are going to have to go to a source you trust, whether that be the internet, a block explorer, Reddit, or a node you trust.